# wxpython + CollapsiblePane doesn't work

Tags: wxpython

I learned today about collapsible panes. But I can't get it to work. the error I get is:

```
"TypeError: in method 'new_CollapsiblePane', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'"
```

I tried to have the collapsible filter as a "def", as a class and included in the class main. And now I am out of ideas.

This is my most recent code:

```
class Main(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, notify_channel=None, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        "some other stuff"
       self.rightsizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
       self.rightsizer.Add(self.listsizer, 80, wx.EXPAND)
       self.rightsizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)

       self.sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
       self.sizer.Add(CollapsibleFilter(self, label="Filter:"), 0, wx.EXPAND)
       self.sizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
       self.sizer.Add(self.rightsizer, 50, wx.EXPAND)
       self.sizer.AddStretchSpacer(2)

       self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
       self.sizer.Fit(self)

class CollapsibleFilter(wx.CollapsiblePane):

    def __init__(self, notify_channel, **kwargs):
      wx.CollapsiblePane.__init__(self,wx.ID_ANY, **kwargs)
      self.notify_channel = notify_channel

      self.CollapsibleFilter=self.GetPane()


      self.filter1 = FilterBox(self.CollapsibleFilter, notify_channel=self.notify_channel)
      self.filter2 = FilterBox(self.CollapsibleFilter, notify_channel=self.notify_channel)
      self.filter3 = FilterBox(self.CollapsibleFilter, notify_channel=self.notify_channel)

      self.filter1.set_dropdown_items(browser_options.filterlist)
      self.filter1.set_dropdown_default(browser_options.default_1)
      self.filter2.set_dropdown_items(browser_options.filterlist)
      self.filter2.set_dropdown_default(browser_options.default_2)
      self.filter3.set_dropdown_items(browser_options.filterlist)
      self.filter3.set_dropdown_default(browser_options.default_3)

      #layout
      self.filtersizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

      self.filtersizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
      self.filtersizer.Add(self.filter1, 60, wx.EXPAND)
      self.filtersizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
      self.filtersizer.Add(self.filter2, 60, wx.EXPAND)
      self.filtersizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
      self.filtersizer.Add(self.filter3, 60, wx.EXPAND)
      self.filtersizer.AddStretchSpacer(1)
```

I hope someone can help me!
Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any widget class it needs to receive a reference to the parent widget when constructed. In your `CollapsibleFilter` class, when it calls the super class `__init__` you are not passing a parent, so that is why it is failing.  Try this:

```
class CollapsibleFilter(wx.CollapsiblePane):
    def __init__(self, parent, notify_channel, **kwargs):
      wx.CollapsiblePane.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, **kwargs)
      ...
```

Comment: Ooooh! Tx it's working! I didn't see it. Today is a fresh day, a fresh mind and I'm ready to program!! :)